# How is Scala so efficient with lists?

Tags: scala

It's usually considered a bad practice to make unnecessary collections in Java as it consumes some memory and CPU. Scala seems to be pretty efficient with it and encourages to use immutable data structures.

How is Scala so efficient with Lists? What techniques are used to achieve that?

Comment: Where is this assumption that "Scala lists are so efficient" coming from? The fact that Scala encourages users to use immutable lists doesn't mean they're efficient. Scala lists are basically singly linked lists.

Comment: What kind of efficeincy are you talking about? The use of immutable data structures has less to do with efficiency and more to do with predictability. There is no such thing as extra and better than Java efficiency with List in Scala.

Comment: Well, list prepend operation is efficient, but other than that, other operations have to involve copying entire collection. As far as i am concerned efficiency of scala collections is simillar to java streams. (But you have to use lazy ones, like scala Stream in order to comparison make any sense)

Comment: Are you talking about the class `List` in particular (linked list in scala), or about the concept of list as an ordered sequence of items in general ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think I've got confused with a prepend operation on lists. Not sure what should I do with the question now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the comments are correct that the claim that list is particularly efficient is a dubious one, it does much better than doing full copies of the collection for every operation like you would do with Java's standard collections.

The reason for this is List and the other immutable collections are not just mutable collections with mutation methods returning a copy, but are designed differently to with immutability in mind.  They Take advantage of something called "structural sharing".  If parts of a collection remain the same after a change, then those parts don't need to be copied and the same object can be shared across multiple collections.  This works because of immutability, there is no change that they could be altered so it's safe to share.

Imagine the simplest example, prepending to a list.

You have a `List(1,2,3)` and you want to prepend 0

```
val original = List(1,2,3)
val updated = 0 :: original
```

You list would then look something like this

```
updated original
    \       \
     0 - - - 1 - - - 2 - - - 3
```

All that's needed is to create a new node and point it's tail to the head of your original list.  Nothing needs to be copied.  Similarly the tail and drop operations just need to return a reference to the appropriate node and nothing needs to be copied.  This is why List can be quite good with the prepend and tail operations, because it doesn't do any copying even though it creates a "new" List.

Other List operations do require some amount copying, but always as little as possible.  As long as part of the tail of a list is unchanged it doesn't need to be copied.  For example when concatenating lists, the first list needs to be copied, but then it's tail can just point to the head of the second, so the second list doesn't need to be copied at all. This is why, when concatenating a long and short list it's better to put the shorter list on the "left" as it is the only one that needs to be copied.

Other types of collections are better at different operations.  Vector for example can to both prepend and append in amortized constant time, as well as having good random access and update capabilities (though still much worse than a raw mutable array).  In most cases it will be more efficient than List while still being immutable. It's implementation is quite complicated. It uses a trie datastructure, with many internal arrays to store data.  The unchanged ones can be shared and only the ones that need to be altered by an update operation need to be copied.